# Three to Four Level Heirarchy with CRUD in Kendo Grid or TreeList

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Does anyone here tried making 3-4 level of hierarchy with CRUD using Grid or TreeListView in Kendo?
I found one but it was written in ASP.NET. Does anyone here know how to convert it to jquery? thanks!
https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/insert-update-delete-hierarchy/defaultcs.aspx?show-source=true

Answer (score 0):

A hierarchical Kendo-UI grid is created by using the grid configuration option `detailInit` to instantiate a sub-grid displaying a properly filtered subset of data corresponding to the sub-grid level.

Converting the ASP.NET example to plain kendo-ui difficult because the asp tags do some server side work that is difficult to tease out into a client only example.

The Kendo-UI for jQuery demo [Grid / Hierarchy](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/hierarchy) shows a 2-level grid.

I created a simplified example in this [Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/IRASUpoZ/4) demonstrating `detailInit` in a 3-level scenario using local data.  Of course real world CRUD datasources will need appropriate server URLs for reading, inserting, updating and deleting records of each level, and that depends on the server side data model.